# Bootstrap media object breaking when using srcset

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, srcset

I am using Bootstrap media objects but they seem to be breaking when I use `srcset`s.

The `media-body` is offset to the right and with `overflow: hidden` it cannot be seen.

When I delete the `srcset` attribute in dev tools it will fix the problem. The working objects in the below screenshot are not using `srcset`.

**BROKEN**[image: Broken media objects]

**EXPECTED**[image] (just ignore the last bath one)

```
<section class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="media media__offer">
      <a href="#">
        <img alt="" src="/heritageCastIron.jpg" srcset="/heritageCastIron.jpg 1x, /heritageCastIron@2x.jpg 2x" class="media-object" />
      </a>
      <div class="media-body">
        <div class="discounts">
          <p class="circle">save <span class="circle-percent">40%</span> off RRP</p>
        </div>
        <h3 class="media-heading"><a href="#">Cast iron baths</a></h3>
        <p class="upper">Special offer!</p>
        <p>RRP from &pound;1,900.00</p>
        <p>Now only:</p>
        <p class="pound">&pound;1215.00</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="media media__offer">
      <a href="/#" class="media-left">
        <img alt="" src="/Ice_5_Tap_hole_BSM.jpg" class="media-object" />
      </a>
      <div class="media-body">
        <div class="discounts">
          <p class="circle">save <span class="circle-percent">70%</span> off RRP</p>
        </div>
        <h3 class="media-heading"><a href="#">Ice 5 Tap Hole Bath Shower Mixer</a></h3>
        <p class="upper">Special offer!</p>
        <p>RRP: &pound;603.00</p>
        <p>Now only:</p>
        <p class="pound">&pound;180.90</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="media media__offer">
      <a href="#" class="media-left">
        <img alt="" src="/Caprieze_Basin_Mixer_TCC04.JPG" class="media-object" />
      </a>
      <div class="media-body">
        <div class="discounts">
          <p class="circle">save <span class="circle-percent">50%</span> off RRP</p>
        </div>
        <h3 class="media-heading"><a href="#">Caprieze Basin Mixer Tap</a></h3>
        <p class="upper">Special offer!</p>
        <p>RRP: &pound;126.26</p>
        <p>Now only:</p>
        <p class="pound">&pound;63.13</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="media media__offer">
      <a href="#" class="media-left">
        <img alt="" src="/BHAFSW00.jpg" srcset="/BHAFSW00.jpg 1x, /BHAFSW00@2x.jpg 2x" class="media-object" />
      </a>
      <div class="media-body">
        <div class="discounts">
          <p class="circle">save <span class="circle-percent">50%</span> off RRP</p>
        </div>
        <h3 class="media-heading"><a href="#">Hadleigh Freestanding Bath</a></h3>
        <p class="upper">Special offer!</p>
        <p>RRP: &pound;1,650.00</p>
        <p>Now only:</p>
        <p class="pound">&pound;825.00</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by **[Bug 1149357](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1149357) - Not setting a width and height on srcset image causes incorrect width for shrink-wrapping ancestor**.

As Elnur Kurtaliev suggests in [Comment 17](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1149357#c17) if you can you should add an explicit `width` attribute on the `img`, or set the width with css.

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="media media__offer">
    <a href="#">
      <img  width="200" alt="" src="/heritageCastIron.jpg" srcset="/heritageCastIron.jpg 1x, /heritageCastIron@2x.jpg 2x" class="media-object" />
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
      <div class="discounts">
        <p class="circle">save <span class="circle-percent">40%</span> off RRP</p>
      </div>
      <h3 class="media-heading"><a href="#">Cast iron baths</a></h3>
      <p class="upper">Special offer!</p>
      <p>RRP from &pound;1,900.00</p>
      <p>Now only:</p>
      <p class="pound">&pound;1215.00</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```